# Is it possible to schedule apps to unlock with applocker?

Tags: powershell, script, automation, group-policy, scheduled-tasks

Programs like [Cold Turkey](https://www.getcoldturkey.com) allow you to set timers for how long apps can run, so I'm wondering why there isn't some code I can put into cmd that stops a program from being opened? With task scheduler, I will then be able to schedule when the apps should run and when they shouldn't.

[Cold Turkey](https://www.getcoldturkey.com) isn't enterprise-grade like applocker nor is it open source, so I have no idea how well it will work on a large-scale or whether it will even be around in 5 years time.

Answer (score 0):

As for ...

> some code I can put into cmd that stops a program from being opened?

...  because, this is a very specialized thing, and it is why AppLocker and other tools like it exist. Not some random .bat, .vbbs, script code hacking thing.

This is really not a PowerShell question or a query about code you've written that is not working or you are confused about.

***So, this is really off topic.***

So, be sure to take time and read the site policies on [How to ask questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

AppLocker is the way you prevent apps from running, some cmd or script. You can use code to set GPO, other polices, even Applocker settings. There is an AppLocker tool to help you with policies,

Here's YouTube video [AaronLocker - by an MSFT and MCS consultant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-IrqFtJOKU) and PowerShell is even part of the demo in the policy configuration effort.